# Github, submodule that is hosted on bitbucket

Tags: git, github, mercurial, bitbucket

I have github repo. There is repo on bitbucket that I need to set as a submodule.  Specfically this: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen

I tried the following:

```
git submodule add https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen
```

but I get:

```
Cloning into 'lib/eigen'...
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen' into submodule path  'lib/eigen' failed
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried to clone it before? test that you can do it regardless of the submodule

Comment: Yes, however I need to use, hg clone https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen not GIT clone